# Proving summation given vectors and orthonormal basis using triangle inequality and cauchy-schwartz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $\{y_1,y_2,...,y_n\}$ be a set of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ and let $\{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$ prove that for every $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ $\in$ $\Bbb R$
>
> $||\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i||^2 \leq  (\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2) (\sum_{i=1}^n ||y_i||^2)$
>
> Part 2 of the question - Prove that if the set of vectors $\{y_1,...,y_n\}$ fulfill $\sum_{i=1}^n||y_i||^2 <1$ then the set $\{u_1+y_1,...,u_n+y_n\}$ is linearly independent
>
> Hint - use the triangle inequality and cauchy schwartz inequality

---

I am struggling to approach it , I was told first I need to prove the triangle inequality so I did the following:
first I did for the basic case , let $a,b \in \Bbb R$ and prove $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$

$\forall a,b \in \Bbb R ,(|a|+|b|)^2 = |a|^2+2|a||b|+|b|^2 \geq a^2+2ab+b^2 $ and since $|x|^2=x^2$ we get $(a+b)^2=|a+b|^2$ from here we get $(|a|+|b|)^2 \geq |a+b|^2$ $\iff$ $|a|+|b| \geq |a+b|^2$

and for the general case I proved using induction for $n \geq 2$
we need to prove $|x_1+...+x_n| \leq |x_1|+...+|x_n|$

1. base case for $n=2$: $|x_1+x_2| \leq |x_1|+|x_n|$ is correct as I just shown
2. assume for $n=k$ :$|x_1+...+x_k| \leq |x_1|+...+|x_k|$
3. induction step for $n=k+1$ : $|x_1+...+x_k +x_{k+1}| \leq |x_1|+...+|x_k|+|x_{k+1}|$ let $\alpha = x_1+...+x_k$ and $\beta = |x_1|+...+|x_k|$ from the property of absolute value that $|x| \geq x$ we get that $\alpha \leq \beta$ therefore $|\alpha +x_{k+1}| \leq \beta +|x_{k+1}|$ and according to our assumption the statement is true and it is the triangle inequality.

But I do not know how this helps with the question itself (again I was told that by the professor this is why I proved it first)

how is $\lambda$ related to things here or even the cauchy schwartz inequality ?
appreciate any tips and hints so I can update my progress

Edit- if $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ is a basis and $\{y_1,y_2,...,y_n\}$ a set of vectors then is $y=\sum_{i=1}^n y_iu_i$ an inner product? .

Edit 2 - I tried the following , since the cauchy schwartz inequality is
$\sum_{i=1}^nu_i \cdot v_i=|(u,v)|\leq ||u||^2 \cdot ||v||^2$
then we get that if  $||\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i||$ then from the triangle inequality and inner product homogeneity $||\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i|| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\lambda_i \cdot y_i|| = \sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i| \cdot ||y_i||  $ and if we square it we get $||\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i||^2 \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2 \sum_{i=1}^n ||y_i||^2$ according to the cauchy schwartz inequality and triangle inequality

Sorry if my English is not all correct hope it is still understandable

Comment: The statement of the problem is a little weird, the two sumation of the RHS are over $i$ which makes it slightly confusing.

Comment: Also curious is introducing an orthonormal basis (the $u_i$) and then not using it in the statement.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It is not so understandable but I think I solved it I am not sure, can you please check the second edit?

Comment: Well I don't think it will be solved until you adress my previous point. In your edit there is a sumation over $i$ that appears magically (the last one). For sure "squaring it" will not give the expression you have afterwards.

Comment: @P.Quinton I don't know what you mean , id you mean the summation in the question itself then it's just from the question , it goes from $i$ to $n$ , if in my first edit then it is something i saw in my textbook that if you have a basis and a set of vrctors then it is a summation of multiplying them and if you mean my last edit I just tried playing with them so it might be wrong? and thank you for the help :) I just don't understand what you mean

Comment: in the expression $\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \| y_i\|^2$, the two summations are using the index $i$, this is typically not recommended. Is this summation intended to be $\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|^2 \sum_{j=1}^n \| y_j\|^2$ ?

Comment: @P.Quinton I thought it has to be the same index , I used the Absolute homogeneity property: $||ax||= |a| ||x||$ for every $x \in V$ and $a \in \Bbb F^n$ (this is from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space ) if it is supposed to be different then I did not know

Comment: @Adamrk Please very carefully compare the formula in your question with the formula that (apparently) somebody asked you to prove, and in particular pay attention to the letters (variable names) used. If there is a difference, please correct your question, but if there are no differences, tell that somebody their question is rubbish.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I rechecked the question , And added the second part of it but the indexes and variables are the same is there a mistake in the question itself? because now it is exactly as it is in the textbook

Comment: @Adamrk The parentheses you added make a huge difference, and the second part explains what the orthonormal basis was there for. It now makes a lot more sense; thank you.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thank you , Is my way correct in some way ? with the triangle inequality and homogeneity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $U$ and $Y$ being matrices having column j as $\mathbf u_j$ and $\mathbf y_j$ respectively, this is can be viewed through Frobenius norms.

The first statement:
$||\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \mathbf y_i||^2=\big \Vert Y\vec{\lambda}\big\Vert_F^2\leq \big \Vert Y\big\Vert_F^2\big \Vert \vec{\lambda}\big\Vert_F^2=\big \Vert \vec{\lambda}\big\Vert_F^2\big \Vert Y\big\Vert_F^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2) (\sum_{i=1}^n ||\mathbf y_i||^2)$
by submultiplicativity of the Frobenius norm.  (If you are not aware of the submultiplicativity of Frobenius norms, consider proving it e.g. by application of Cauchy-Schwarz and triangle inequality.)

For the second part
$\big \Vert U^T Y\big \Vert_F^2 =\big \Vert Y\big \Vert_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n ||\mathbf y_i||^2 \lt 1$
implies that, when working over $\mathbb C$, all eigenvalues of $U^TY$ have modulus $\lt 1$-- justifying this either in terms of the operator 2 norm or by the inequality of Schur: $\sum_{k=1}^n \vert \lambda_k\vert^2 \leq \big \Vert U^T Y\big \Vert_F^2$. Finally

$\big \vert\det\big(U+Y\big)\big \vert = \big \vert\det\big(U\big)\det\big(I+U^TY\big)\big \vert= \big \vert\det\big(I+U^TY\big)\big \vert $
$= \prod_{k=1}^n \vert(1+\lambda_k)\vert\geq \prod_{k=1}^n (\vert 1\vert-\vert\lambda_k\vert) =  \prod_{k=1}^n ( 1-\vert\lambda_k\vert)\gt 0$
by reverse triangle inequality